# error of OpenLayers plugin in QGIS

Tags: error, qgis-openlayers-plugin, google

After the opening of Google Satellite through the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS, it shows the error

> "For Development process only"

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Its look like that you need a Google API key.
In this [address](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) you can get one. 
Just be sure that you you are not violating their copyrights.